# Can we use would in the following sentence?

Tags: conditional-constructions

> If we eradicate corruption, our economy **would/ will** improve.

I read that "would" is used to indicate possibility.

Comment: Sentence looks strange. I would use our economy would/will *improve*.

Comment: Agreed @RuchirM why use 'be'?

Answer (score 1):

Both would and will can be used but they have subtle difference here. Will indicates there is much more surety that economy will improve. Would is on more hopeful side means it is not very hopeful but economy may improve or so we hope. So will is used when it is much more certain that a thing will happen.

Answer (score 1):

To me, each of these refers to a conditional result, the first to a present immediate condition and its result, and thus to the near future, the second to a remote condition and its result, and thus to a time further in the future, possibly so far in the future that it might never occur.

> If we eradicate corruption, the economy will improve.
>
> If we eradicated corruption, the economy would improve.

Answer (score 0):

> If we **eradicated** corruption, our economy **would** improve.

suggests there would have been **improvement** in the economy if they had **eradicated** by now

> If we **eradicate** corruption, our economy **will** improve.

has more certainty in emphasis.

In terms of your original post

> If we **eradicate** corruption, our economy **will have** more progress.
>   If we **eradicated** corruption, our economy **would have** more progress.
>   If we **eradicated** corruption, there **would be** more progress in our economy.

Answer (score 0):

**Would** is the best one to use as it is for "**imagined hypothesis**", like in the sentence "If we eradicate corruption, our economy **would** improve."

(Something thats more concrete/certain we can use '**will**', like "If the temperature of the water goes below 0C, it **will** start to freeze.")